# Публикация сообщений на стену сообщества

Tags: facebook, facebook-api

Как постить на стенку сообщества от имени самой страницы (сообщества) facebook [stream.publish](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/)?

При указании `target_id` он постит на стенку от текущего пользователя, а нужно от имени сообщества. Подскажите, плз.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно указать параметр post_as_page = идентификатор страницы

```
$ret_obj = $facebook->api("/{$page_id}/feed", 'POST',
       array(
            'post_as_page'     => $page_id',
            ...
       )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Нет дело не в этом, нужен был токен страницы а не пользователя.